# JTables simultaneos

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Olá, eu gostaria de saber se há forma de selecionar 2 JTables simultaneamente, vou explicar:

eu preciso que algumas colunas do meu JTable, não se alterem quando o JScrollBar da horizontal seja alterado, segundo minhas pesquisas, não há como eu fazer isso diretamente, então terei de fazer uma gambiarra e deixar 2 JTables simultaneos funcionando no mesmo Model.

entretanto, na hora de selecionar, vejo que vou precisar selecionar as 2 JTables (já que o scrollbar da vertical vai ser simultaneo) para mostrar ao usuário com qual registro ele está mexendo.

se alguém souber como faz isso, selecionar a segunda tabela, mas deixando o foco na primeira, eu agradeço

ou se alguém souber como deixar determinada coluna independente de um scrollbar, eu também agradeço, pois facilitaria muito!

Comment: Como assim? Você quer que ao selecionar uma linha em uma tabela, selecione a mesma na outra? Elas tem a mesma quantidade de dados?

Comment: sim, elas tem sim a mesma quantidade de dados, vou explicar melhor: a tabela que estou trabalhando é de cartão ponto, onde tem data, dia semana, folga, feriado, entradas e saidas, e total, mas as entradas e saidas sao dinamicas, ou seja, pode ter mais ou menos, caso o scrollpane fique maior que a tela, ele deve mover apenas da primeira entrada pra frente, deixando fixo as outras colunas, por isso vou separar em 2 tabelas, mas de qualquer maneira, sim, eles tem a mesma quantidade de dados! Se souber uma maneira mais simples do que essa gambiarra, eu agradeço :D

Comment: você está querendo fazer algo semelhante ao cabeçalho de planilhas do excel, onde a primeira linha fica fixa enquanto as outras se movem no scroll? Acho que não é possivel fazer isso utilizando JTable.

Comment: isso mesmo, mas ao invés de linhas, fazer com colunas fixas entende? e sim, tem como sim, um jeito é dividir a tabela em 2 e, adicionar o scrollpane da horizontal apenas em 1 das tabelas, enquanto a outra se mantém fixa, independente do scroll horizontal, enquanto eu deixo o scroll vertical das 2 simultaneos, como nesse tópico: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12060587/how-to-scroll-two-or-more-jtables-with-a-single-scrollbar  O problema é realmente a visualização, se eu colocar uma tabela mas não selecionar a outra, é complicado analisar o registro que está trabalhando!

Comment: Podes exemplificar o funcionamento que você espera das suas tabelas com alguma figura? Acho que estou começando a entender como resolver.

Comment: exemplo 1: http://prntscr.com/b5ko7e  exemplo2: http://prntscr.com/b5knwl  fiz essa printzinha no excel, note que as 4 primeiras colunas não se movem no exemplo 2, onde a coluna "Feriado" está "sobrescrevendo" a coluna adicional, o sistema tem que funcionar do mesmo jeito, print do sistema (sem as colunas fixas): http://prntscr.com/b5kpf7  no meu sistema, note que tenho até a coluna "Feriado" que não contém hora (HH:mm) e, essas colunas servem pro usuário se localizar dentro da aplicação, por isso preciso que ela seja fixa como nos exemplos, se precisar de um melhor, me avise :) Obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema utilizando MouseListener nas 2 tabelas:

O único problema é que tem um pequeno Delay para selecionar a outra tabela, quando seleciona a primeira.

```
tb2.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            row = tbFin.getSelectedRow();
            col = tbFin.getSelectedColumn();
            tb2.setRowSelectionInterval(row, row);
            tb2.setColumnSelectionInterval(col, col);
            tb1.setRowSelectionInterval(row, row);
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        }
    });

    tb1.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            row = tbIn.getSelectedRow();
            col = tbIn.getSelectedColumn();
            tb1.setRowSelectionInterval(row, row);
            tb1.setColumnSelectionInterval(col, col);
            tb2.setRowSelectionInterval(row, row);
        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        }

    });
```